# Origin of "twitter"

Tags: etymology, verbs

A non-native English speaker said on television that the word *twitter* originated from an English verb *to twite*, which means *to twitter*. Is this true?
Does the verb *twite* exist at all?

Comment: Before considering whether it is true or not, the argument does not make sense to me.  “Twitter” originated from “to twite,” whose meaning is “to twitter”??  Which is the first, twitter or “twite”?

Comment: [twitter](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=twitter&searchmode=none) at etymonline?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi - Why does it not make any sense to you? Just replace "to twitter" with "to make small short sounds" and it will make sense. When he said "whose meaning is to "twitter"", he was speaking about the meaning of the word, not the spelling or pronunciation.

Comment: @mitch EtymOnline doesn't explain that "to twite" actually is a verb, and there is another (rare) definition of "twitter"

Comment: I disagree with the close votes on the grounds that the OED shows a meaning of *twitter* which does, actually, stem from *to twite*. The EtymOnline entry doesn't cover this possibility.

Comment: @simchona - What does "close votes" mean?

Comment: @brilliant: When you get 3k rep, you can vote to close a question for the same reasons you flag it (general reference, not a real question, etc.). If 5 people vote, the question is closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary *does* include an entry for *twitter* which is based on the verb *to twit*. A *twitter* is one who *twits*, that is:

> *trans*. To blame, find fault with, censure, reproach, upbraid (a person), esp. in a light or annoying way; to cast an imputation upon; to taunt.

The etymology for this verb is:

> **Etymology**:  ***Originally twite*** (with long i), aphetic form of atwite v.1, q.v.

Tracing back, the etymology of *atwite* is:

> **Etymology**:  < at- prefix1 + Old English wítan to blame, reproach; compare Old English oðwítan. The modern twit n.1, formerly twite, is an aphetized form of this word.

So the verb *to twite* did exist and spawned a related noun. However, this is not the same *twitter* that is used for the sound of a bird. In the case of a bird, *twitter* is both noun and verb. In this case, the etymology of the verb is:

> **Etymology**:  Of imitative origin: compare Old High German zwizirôn, -erôn (Middle High German zwitzern, German zwitschern), Dutch kwetteren, and Swedish qvittra, Norwegian dialect kvittra, kvitra, Danish kvidre (see quitter v.2), in sense 1

The onomatopoeia also *predates* the verb *to twite*. The form in which a bird *twitters* emerged with Chaucer in 1374. The form in which a person *twitters* to tattle-tale appeared in 1530. So *twitter* to refer to the sound of a bird is an onomatopoeia. It does *not*, however, come from the verb "to twite" although there is another definition of *twitter* which does. The two homonyms come from different roots, although they currently have the same form.

Answer (score 4):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=twitter&searchmode=none) says:

> **twitter (v.)**
>   late 14c., *twiteren*, in reference to birds, of imitative origin (cf. O.H.G. *zwizziron*, Ger. *zwitschern*, Dan. *kvidre*, O.Swed. *kvitra*). The noun meaning "condition of tremulous excitement" is attested from 1670s. The microblogging service with the 140-character limit was introduced in 2006.

It appears, then, that the origin is [onomatopoeic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia).  The noun *[twite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/twite)*, referring to a type of finch, is also attested to have imitative origins:

> 1555–65;  imitative

Also, if *twiting* ever was a verb, it sure doesn't show up anywhere in cyberspace.  I googled for *twited*, *twiting*, *to twite*, etc, and came up with nil.  *[Twit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/twit)* is a verb, and *twite* and *twites* are nouns, but there is no such verb.

Comment: It seems that the verb should have been "tweeting", when referring to Twitter

Answer (score -1):

A Twite is a small bird, a member of the finch family.

It is from its name that we get the word "twitter", which describes the fast, chatty noise it makes.

The web service Twitter was most likely (it is a common belief, but as far as I know unconfirmed) named after this, to exemplify it usage of rapid-fire short (<140 character) messages.

So, 'twitter' in this sense describes the conversation itself, with each message being a 'tweet' (or 'twit' in the original spelling)

Comment: This answer would be much improved by referencing your source for the information that the word "twitter" comes from the name of the twite.

Comment: If *twitter* is onomatopoeic, why is the word *twite* relevant to its origin at all?

Comment: Fair point DRM, I chose the wrong word there. My mistake.

Comment: But it *is* onomatopoeic!

Comment: Actually, my original meaning was that it was named the Twite because it twitters. So, I guess, twitter is onomatopoeic, as is Twite.